# Cannot read property 'hasAttached' of undefined at MatDialogContainer.attachComponentPortal

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog

Mat dialog is not opening and its throwing this error.
I also attached the parent component and dialog codes.

```
core.js:6272 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttached' of undefined
at MatDialogContainer.attachComponentPortal (dialog.js:187)
at MatDialog._attachDialogContent (dialog.js:797)
at MatDialog.open (dialog.js:675)
at parentComponent.openJustMeDialog (.component.ts:121)
at parentComponent_div_0_Template_span_click_19_listener (parent.component.html:28)
at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:22086)
at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:22128)
at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:976)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41916)
```

**Parent component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
    import { justMeDialog } from './justme-dialog/justme.dialog';
   @Component({
   selector: 'app-parent',
   templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
   })
  export class parentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {
  }

  openJustMeDialog(){
    let justMeDialogRef = this.dialog.open(justMeDialog); <--- this one is throwing error
   }
 }
```

**Dialog component**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-justMeDialog',
  templateUrl: 'justme.dialog.html',
  styleUrls: ['justme.dialog.css']
})
export class justMeDialog {

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

I also imported the mat dialog module to app module.

Comment: did u add justMeDialog  in entryComponents  ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MatDialog, but I expect that you must add parameters to the constructor of justMeDialog. I found an example on https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-dialog/ where the constructor has parameters `private fb: FormBuilder, private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CourseDialogComponent>`

Comment: @hanan yes i added it to entry components still its throwing this error.

Comment: Please create an example in stackblatz

Answer (score 3):

Please check the angular material version.
Make sure using compatible version i have updated my material version
to.  "@angular/material": "^10.0.0",

```
 },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^10.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.11.0",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.11.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
```

"@angular/material": "^10.0.0", "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.0",
after updating angular material version the issue is resolved.