# TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttached' of undefined

Tags: angular

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttached' of undefined
    at MatDialogContainer.attachComponentPortal (dialog.js:184)
    at MatDialog._attachDialogContent (dialog.js:793)
    at MatDialog.open (dialog.js:671)
```

I got this error when I update my angular 7 to 10 . Anyone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62790937/cannot-read-property-hasattached-of-undefined-at-matdialogcontainer-attachcomp