# Why Dialog box is opening partially at the left side of the page?

Tags: angular

I am building an Angular app. I used a MatDialog in my login component. but It is not working properly. It should render center of the page. But it is rendering on left side of the page. Can anyone help me please?
code on my header.component.html:

```html
<span class="flex-spacer"></span>
<a mat-button (click)="openLoginForm()"><span class="fa fa-sign-in fa-lg"></span>Login</a>
```

code on my header.component.ts:

```js
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
}
openLoginForm() {
    this.dialog.open(LoginComponent, { width: '500px', height: '450px' });
}
```

Image:[image]

Here is my package.json file:

```
    {
      "name": "con-fusion",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~11.2.13",
        "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
        "@angular/common": "~11.2.13",
        "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.13",
        "@angular/core": "~11.2.13",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
        "@angular/forms": "~11.2.13",
        "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.13",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.13",
        "@angular/router": "~11.2.13",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.12",
        "@angular/cli": "~11.2.12",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.13",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "karma": "~6.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "~4.1.5"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Check the console for errors. This usually happens when an error occurs in the modal component.

Comment: @superiom console is showing the following error:vendor.js:64003 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttached' of undefined
    at MatDialogContainer.attachComponentPortal (vendor.js:30433)
    at MatDialog._attachDialogContent (vendor.js:30970)
    at MatDialog.open (vendor.js:30865)
    at HeaderComponent.openLoginForm (main.js:1212)
    at HeaderComponent_Template_a_click_16_listener (main.js:1239)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (vendor.js:73072)

Comment: Can you post the package.json file into your question?

Comment: @LingVu, here I add  my Package.json file.

Comment: You can try to update the angular material version to 10 or 11, npm install and run again. Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62790937/cannot-read-property-hasattached-of-undefined-at-matdialogcontainer-attachcomp

Answer (score 4):

You need to add in app.module:

```
entryComponents: [ name of the dialog component]
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

The version of the angular libraries need to be compatible with each other. Usually most of them shares the same version number. In this case, try to change your @angular/material package to `~11.2.13`(and also the cdk seems to be outdated).

You can find all available versions under `Versions`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/material

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "@angular/cdk": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/material": "~11.2.13",
    ...
  },
```

Don't forget to `npm install` after saving your `package.json`.

Comment: after changing package.json and then npm install it is not finding any material module. ex:Module '"@angular/material/toolbar"' has no exported member 'MatToolbarModule'.

Comment: it is working.. thanks. but icon item is not showing.. i am using font-awesome 4.7.0

Comment: @BarunBepart I have the same problem. Managed to solve? how?